# Using Vector pdf Image in Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.IOS visual studio project, I wanted to use Vector pdf image in an UIImageView. But I am not able to add the vector image directly in the storyboard designer (also tried drag-drop).

Is there a way to use Vector pdf image in xamarin IOS? 
Any sample would be much helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, As lowleetak said, We need to add the pdf file into the asset first.

Xamarin tutorial [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/displaying-an-image/#Using-Vector-Images-in-Asset-Catalogs) , just follow the step ,it's simple.

**Edit**:

> there is no option to select the Attributes Inspector for setting the Scales to Single Vector in Visual Studio. Is there an alternative for this?

AFAIK,there is no option to set the scale for the vector , maybe you could set this property when generate the pdf file.

> I want to handle click event to capture the image X Y co-ordinates in C#. Is there a way to do this?

Override the touch event . documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/touch/touch_in_ios/).

Code :

```
public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    var touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;
    CGPoint point = touch.GetPreciseLocation(yourImage);
}
```

**Update:**

- On iPhone5:

[image]

- On iPhone6

[image]

And this are the constraints

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cole. I was able to use the add the vector image.
but the problem is in Capturing the X Y coordinate of the Image. If I use Touches/LocationInView - it gives the coordinates of the screen. whereas I want the XY points of the Vector Image in UIImageView. Is there any way to get this??

Comment: @Praddy  set the detecting view to your image , it will auto calculate the coordinate inside the image .   CGPoint point = touch.GetPreciseLocation(yourImage);

Comment: my touch,
public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {  base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
            UITouch touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;
            string pos = "X" + touch.GetPreciseLocation(VectorImage).X + "Y" + touch.GetPreciseLocation(VectorImage).Y; }

In my case, for different screen size, it should return the same X Y coordinates of the Image. ex: same Image in Iphone 5s & Iphone6 should return the same XY when touched in the same point. 
However, this touch returns me the actual XY from left and top of the View position.

Comment: @Praddy are you using autolayout, how you set the constraint for the image.

Comment: @Praddy did this code work ? CGPoint point = touch.GetPreciseLocation(yourImage);

Comment: I have 2 Vertical and 2 Horizontal constarins pointing to left, top, right & bottom. so I guess, its auto layout.

Comment: @Praddy ok, so you set the margin to its superview right? different  screen size  comes to  different size for the image, it's reason why you got the different XY when pointing the same position.

Comment: @Praddy Set left, top . width ,height  with constraints. Keep the same size and then have a try.

Comment: @Praddy please see my test result in updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the pdf images to asset catalog first (Images.xcassets). You can refer to the guide [HERE](https://icons8.com/articles/how-to-use-vectors-in-xcode-7/). It is a guide for Xcode but should be quite the same in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks lowleetak. I am able to add the pdf image now, However, there is no option to select the Attributes Inspector for setting the Scales to Single Vector in Visual Studio. Is there an alternative for this?

Also, I want to handle click event to capture the image X Y co-ordinates in C#. Is there a way to do this? Any suggestions are welcome.